# How to determine if the InnoSetup installation is successful

Tags: inno-setup

Through code, is there is any way to know whether an installation succeeded or failed? I need to revert database updates incase the installation failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DeinitializeSetup()` event for monitoring that.

From documentation:

> Called just before Setup terminates.
>   Note that this function is called even
>   if the user exits Setup before
>   anything is installed.

More details at [Inno Setup Events](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm).

Comment: You forgot to mention what to write inside the body of the `DeinitializeSetup` procedure (which is far from obvious, as far as I can see).

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I think you're doing it backwards. Instead of reverting database updates if the install fails, perform the updates only if the installation succeeds.

Now that the actions are in this order, put the database updates in [`CurStepChanged`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm) in an
`if CurStep=ssDone` block, and they'll only happen after a successful install.

Another option is to perform the updates in the `[Run]` section, which happens after everything in `[Files]` has been processed (see [Installation Order](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installorder)) and after the Cancel button has been disabled.